# Header issues while using wxWidgets on Xcode

Tags: xcode, wxwidgets

I did almost everything listed on this wiki page: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Creating_Xcode_projects_for_wxWidgets_applications

except for:

> Copy the "Preprocessor macros" lines (still in Build Settings) from the project "minimal_cocoa.xcodeproj" to your main project.

And I typed the Marcos on the following image of that wiki.

But there were still troubles:
[image: exception]

and it seemed that `"wx/defs.h"` is fine, locating in its directory. I don't know what to do. Can I solve this problem or find some alternative way?

**Xcode**: 8.2.1 **wxWidgets**: 3.1.0 (I tried 3.0.2 but it couldn't compile:)

Comment: I've never followed the wiki procedure, but you clearly have a problem with `wx.xcconfig` being not found. Try fixing this, presumably by copying the missing file from `build/wx`.

Comment: @virtualize, you are trying to build your own code, right?

Comment: @virtualize, I also presume you compiled the library in the Terminal?

Comment: @Igor, yes, I think I have complied following the instructions.

Comment: @VZ: I think `wx.xcconfig` is in `wxWidgets-3.1.0/build/osx`

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo, it's indeed `build/osx`.

Comment: @VZ It is there absolutely, but I just don't know what to do.

Comment: Err, copy it to the directory containing your project as I wrote in my first comment?